# Display product quantity for wholesale

Tags: magento-1.9, product, quantity

Simple one but cant find it. How do i display quantity of a product for a group only (wholesale)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a customer group?

Comment: yep only wanted to show it for wholesale group

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code.

```
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
      $groupId = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
      $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
      if ('wholesale' == $group->getCode()){ //or $group->getCustomerGroupCode() 
        $qty = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
        echo 'Available quantity is ' . $qty;
    }
}
```

Comment: what directory? view.phtml?

Comment: Yes, in view.phtml

Comment: You can enable the template path hints to know the blocks and the template files being called on the page.

Comment: How to add a wholesale qty after quantity section inventory admin